Plot body heatmap
Can a heatmap be applied to this body plot based on a statistic by body part?
library(tidyverse)
library(humapr)

body_data <- tibble(loc = c(
  "head", "neck", "chest", "abdomen", "arm",
  "forearm", "hand", "thigh", "leg", "foot"
))

body_data |> 
  humap() +
  geom_body(aes(loc = loc), annotate = NA)


EDIT: Thanks to Carl's response I could test some ideas on this package, but I got some issues:
In the moment I combine bodyparts into a fewer ones, side argument does not work properly. There is the example of code that I used:
body_data <- data.frame(loc = sampler(c("head", "neck", "chest", "abdomen", "arm", 
                                        "forearm", "hand", "thigh", "leg", "foot"), 200),
                        side = sampler(c("left", "right"), 200),
                        gender = sample(c("male", "female"), 200, TRUE),
                        year = 1)
humap() + 
  geom_body(aes(loc = loc, side = side), data = body_data, combine = 
              list(`Upper extremities` = c("arm", "forearm","hand"),
                   `Lower extremities` = c("thigh","leg","foot"),
                   `Trunk` = c("abdomen","chest"),
                   `Head & neck` = c("head","neck"))) 

This is the error I get:
Procesing your data yielded 100 missing values:
Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

When I get rid of side argument it works as expected, but I need to represent both sides.

take a look at: https://github.com/josedv82/bdgramR/blob/master/README.md

library(tidyverse)
library(humapr)

body_data <- tibble(loc = c(
  rep("head", 3), "neck", rep("chest", 6), "abdomen", "arm",
  rep("forearm", 7), "hand", rep("thigh", 8), "leg", "foot"
))

body_data |> 
  humap() +
  geom_body(aes(loc = loc)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "H")


Created on 2024-04-02 with reprex v2.1.0
With the side argument`:
library(tidyverse)
library(humapr)

set.seed(1)
body_data <- data.frame(
  loc = sample(c(
    "head", "neck", "chest", "abdomen", "arm",
    "forearm", "hand", "thigh", "leg", "foot"
  ), 200, TRUE),
  side = sample(c("left", "right"), 200, TRUE),
  gender = sample(c("male", "female"), 200, TRUE),
  year = 1
)
humap() +
  geom_body(aes(loc = loc, side = side), annotate = "all",
    data = body_data, combine =
      list(
        `Upper extremities` = c("arm", "forearm", "hand"),
        `Lower extremities` = c("thigh", "leg", "foot"),
        `Trunk` = c("abdomen", "chest"),
        `Head & neck` = c("head", "neck")
      )
  ) 


Created on 2024-04-05 with reprex v2.1.0

Thank you for the answer! How do I put summary values (% for example) instead of frequencies?

The documentation indicates: "When using stat = "identity", you must supply the name of the column with the summary statistic as the fill aesthetic", which would suggest something like geom_body(aes(loc = loc, fill = stat), stat = "identity") but it's not clear how to then control the annotation, so may be worth a Github issue.

Thank you Carl, it works for me sometimes, but most of time I get error. I did a brief edit to the post to add a new issue I get when trying to use side parameter. Nevertheless, this package is very outdated, I wish there was any alternative to plot human bodies, it would be very useful on medical research camp...

Should really be a new question, but it works with the side argument for me.  See the added example. It should be sample() rather than sampler().

Also added annotate = "all" in case you want to see your new combination labels.
